# Reject binary while status is "Upload Received"

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I uploaded my binary for review then shortly after I discovered a small issue which requires rejecting the binary and uploading a new one.

In my app details, the Binary Details link isn't there so I can't reject the binary. I was wondering if this is the way it is supposed to be or this is a bug in iTunes Connect. Also is there any other way I could reject this binary without having to wait for its status to change to "Waiting for Review"?

Comment: You have probably already handled this, but I'd say wait till "Waiting for Review." This transition shouldn't take more than a few minutes to happen.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had to wait till the app status changed to "Waiting for Review" to reject the binary. The problem is that it got stuck on the "Upload Received" status for a long while.

Comment: Really Apple? Really!?